# Convert values in a dictionary of dictionaries in ansible

Tags: ansible

I have a list of hostnames in a dictionary of dictionaries currently as follows:

```yaml
vars:
    clusters:
        homelab:
            agents:
                - knode-01
                - knode-02
            servers:
                - kmaster-01
                - kmaster-02
                - kmaster-03
        remotelab:
            agents:
            servers:
                - rmaster-01
                - rmaster-02
                - rmaster-03
```

I want to convert this structure to the corresponding IP addresses:

```yaml
    cluster_ips:
        homelab:
            agents:
                - 192.168.0.91
                - 192.168.0.92
            servers:
                - 192.168.0.81
                - 192.168.0.82
                - 192.168.0.83
        remotelab:
            agents:
            servers:
                - 192.168.1.81
                - 192.168.1.82
                - 192.168.1.83
```

My hosts file looks like this:

```yaml
---
all:
  hosts:
    kmaster-01:
      ansible_host: 192.168.0.81
    kmaster-02:
      ansible_host: 192.168.0.82
    kmaster-03:
      ansible_host: 192.168.0.83
    knode-01:
      ansible_host: 192.168.0.91
    knode-02:
      ansible_host: 192.168.0.92
    rmaster-01:
      ansible_host: 192.168.1.81
    rmaster-02:
      ansible_host: 192.168.1.82
    rmaster-03:
      ansible_host: 192.168.1.83
```

For simple structures I know I can `map('extract', hostvars, ['ansible_host'])` but for such a more extensive structure, I am not sure how to navigate this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the global variables

```yaml
  homelab:
    agents: [knode-01, knode-02]
    servers: [kmaster-01, kmaster-02, kmaster-03]
  remotelab:
    agents: []
    servers: [rmaster-01, rmaster-02, rmaster-03]
```

Start with the simple structure and create the dictionary

```yaml
  ah_dict: "{{ dict(ansible_play_hosts_all|
                    zip(ansible_play_hosts_all|
                        map('extract', hostvars, ['ansible_host']))) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
 ah_dict:
    kmaster-01: 192.168.0.81
    kmaster-02: 192.168.0.82
    kmaster-03: 192.168.0.83
    knode-01: 192.168.0.91
    knode-02: 192.168.0.92
    rmaster-01: 192.168.1.81
    rmaster-02: 192.168.1.82
    rmaster-03: 192.168.1.83
```

Then, use it to convert the lists

```yaml
  homelab_ip: "{{ dict(homelab.keys()|
                       zip(homelab.values()|
                           map('map', 'extract', ah_dict))) }}"
  remotelab_ip: "{{ dict(remotelab.keys()|
                         zip(remotelab.values()|
                             map('map', 'extract', ah_dict))) }}"
```

give what you want

```yaml
  homelab_ip:
    agents: [192.168.0.91, 192.168.0.92]
    servers: [192.168.0.81, 192.168.0.82, 192.168.0.83]

  remotelab_ip:
    agents: []
    servers: [192.168.1.81, 192.168.1.82, 192.168.1.83]
```

---

- Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    homelab:
      agents: [knode-01, knode-02]
      servers: [kmaster-01, kmaster-02, kmaster-03]
    remotelab:
      agents: []
      servers: [rmaster-01, rmaster-02, rmaster-03]

    ah_dict: "{{ dict(ansible_play_hosts_all|
                      zip(ansible_play_hosts_all|
                          map('extract', hostvars, ['ansible_host']))) }}"
    homelab_ip: "{{ dict(homelab.keys()|
                         zip(homelab.values()|
                             map('map', 'extract', ah_dict))) }}"
    remotelab_ip: "{{ dict(remotelab.keys()|
                           zip(remotelab.values()|
                               map('map', 'extract', ah_dict))) }}"

  tasks:

    - block:
        - debug:
            var: ah_dict
        - debug:
            var: homelab_ip|to_yaml
        - debug:
            var: remotelab_ip|to_yaml
      run_once: true
```

---

- If you want to put all clusters into a dictionary

```yaml
    clusters:
      homelab:
        agents: [knode-01, knode-02]
        servers: [kmaster-01, kmaster-02, kmaster-03]
      remotelab:
        agents: []
        servers: [rmaster-01, rmaster-02, rmaster-03]
```

it is easier to iterate the structure in a Jinja template

```yaml
    ah_dict: "{{ dict(ansible_play_hosts_all|
                      zip(ansible_play_hosts_all|
                          map('extract', hostvars, ['ansible_host']))) }}"
    clusters_ip: |
      {% filter from_yaml %}
      {% for cluster,groups in clusters.items() %}
      {{ cluster }}:
      {% for group,hosts in groups.items() %}
        {{ group }}: {{ hosts|map('extract', ah_dict) }}
      {% endfor %}
      {% endfor %}
      {% endfilter %}
```

gives

```yaml
  clusters_ip:
    homelab:
      agents: [192.168.0.91, 192.168.0.92]
      servers: [192.168.0.81, 192.168.0.82, 192.168.0.83]
    remotelab:
      agents: []
      servers: [192.168.1.81, 192.168.1.82, 192.168.1.83]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it is close to what I want to achieve. I have realised I have not been entirely accurate in the description of my problemm. I fixed the question with additional variable names.

Comment: Is it possible to do this in one step or is it completely out of question with ansible?

Comment: Yes. It is possible. I added the example.